# 16.04.3: setting eth interface down to get wifi interface work

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 on a dual-boot machine together with Windows 10 64bit. Secure boot is enabled. Here's my network configuration:

```
root@marco-X580VD:/home/marco# ifconfig
enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW 10:7b:44:38:f2:61  
          indirizzo inet:192.168.2.10  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4360 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3432 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:4659173 (4.6 MB)  Byte TX:339071 (339.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Loopback locale  
          indirizzo inet:127.0.0.1  Maschera:255.0.0.0
          indirizzo inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:45 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:45 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:2592 (2.5 KB)  Byte TX:2592 (2.5 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW ac:ed:5c:90:70:fe  
          indirizzo inet:192.168.2.2  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
          indirizzo inet6: fe80::fe72:7377:ab89:e0d8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:97009 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:133427625 (133.4 MB)  Byte TX:6135630 (6.1 MB)
```

Plus routing:

```
root@marco-X580VD:/home/marco# route
Tabella di routing IP del kernel
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.2.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp4s0
default         192.168.2.254   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp4s0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

My wifi/ethernet router's ip is `192.168.2.254`. This is the default configuration showing up when I start Ubuntu and connect to the wifi lan. The static ip for `enp4s0` is defined in `/etc/network/interfaces`, while `wlp3s0` is managed by the NetworkManager, and the configuration is currently set to DHCP. I'm able to access the Internet because of the wired connection: in fact, plugging out the ethernet cable results in no internet connection at all: that's because I can't ping my router, albeit `wlp3s0` is configured to do so. However, setting `enp4s0` down through `ifconfig` re-establishes successfully the connection, so I was wondering if this strange behavior is caused by some clashing. Do I have to set it down explicitly in order to connect via wifi? Also, switching wifi on/off repeatedly has no effect. This happens only if eth config is up, regardless of the eth cable being connected or not.